# How can Auto submit a html page that use php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a PHP page that have a HTML form.this form filled by PHP and i don't want to show this page. i want to auto submit this form without click on submit button.
my code is:

```
<code>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('Form').submit();
    </script>
</code>
```

how to do this work?

Comment: You misspelled `getElemetById` its `getElementById`

Comment: did you call this page in back end?

Comment: you can use jquery ajax on the another page insted and send the data as the another or this page loads

Comment: @Gopal yes i want to work this page in back end.

Comment: Put the form on the same page and use `$(document).ready(function(){


      $('form').submit(function(event){
      var $url = 'to send the data';
       event.preventDefault();
        var $query = $('form').serialize();
        $.get($url, $query , function(data){
         alert('data received');
        });
      });

 $('form').submit();
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to trigger the form submit when the page is fully loaded including graphics.

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  document.getElementById('Form').submit();
});
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: I' trying all this solution, but this don't  work in page. i do this work in another page and work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

in jquery

```
$( "#submit-button" ).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can submit using form tag name

```
document.forms["formId"].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use $( document ).ready(function() { }); in the form page.like this

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('Form').submit();
});
</script>
```

here when you call this page it will submit the form automatically.